# copy lines based on matching pattern in bash

Tags: bash

I need to copy certain lines out of a file, basically user data that meets a match. For example look at this partial file:

```
    user0:
        password = passw0rd
        lastupdate = 1205877833
        flags = 

    user1:
        password = *
        lastupdate = 1205877833
        flags = 

    user2:
        password = *
        lastupdate = 1205877833
        flags = 

    user3:
        password = passw0rd
        lastupdate = 1205877833
        flags =
```

I want to search for a match on some string like **"password = *"**  and print the user entries (which are separated by a blank line),

Example, search for users with "password = *"  and print them like this,

**SAMPLE OUTPUT :**

```
    user1:
        password = *
        lastupdate = 1205877833
        flags = 

    user2:
        password = *
        lastupdate = 1205877833
        flags =
```

Hopefully this makes sense, thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks like an "ini" format, would you be adverse to using python or perl?

Comment: I'm writing a bash script so I would prefer not to call perl or python but if it's a better way ...

Comment: Does the file you are working with always have those spaces at the start of each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this. The only thing is you have to quote regex patterns. Or you could just use regex patterns if you like.

```
awk -v p='password = [*]' -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '$0 ~ p' file
```

Here's a regex form also that's less confusing:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/password = [*]/' file
```

Output:

```
    user1:
        password = *
        lastupdate = 1205877833
        flags = 

    user2:
        password = *
        lastupdate = 1205877833
        flags =
```

Here's also a Ruby code in which you wouldn't need quoting:

```
ruby -00 -e 'p = "password = *"; re = Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(p)); while gets; puts $_ if re =~ $_; end' file
```

It gives same output.

Comment: '$0 ~ p' in your awk line is enough, '.*' around p is useless.

Comment: @lihao You're correct. My first form is like that but something didn't work. Perhaps the reason was different. Thanks btw.

Comment: Thanks for the FAST response, one other thing, what if I wanted to search for something else like "password =[[:alnum:]]*" vs "password = [[:alnum:]]*"?  I need to look for password =pass (no space after =)

Comment: @konsolebox can you explain a bit the `awk` mechanism at stake?

Comment: @MikeQ I made an update for that in which you can actually use regex.

Comment: @EduardLopez With `RS` set to empty value, awk goes paragraph mode in which one paragraph is processed every loop.

Comment: @konsolebox, Thank you very much!  I'm all set except that I can not figure out how to show results for user =1234 ( where there is no space between = and the password 1234)...

Answer (score 0):

If your section always have the same structure (number of lines) you can use `fgrep`:

### Solution

**Update:** use `fgrep` of `grep -F` otherwise the `*` is interpreted.

```
fgrep 'password = *' -B 1 -A 2 input.txt
```

**Disclaimer**: this approach is highly **tailored to your problem, inconsistent number of line per section will produce incoherent results**.

See [explanation](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep%20%27password%20%3D%20*%27%20-B%201%20-A%202%20input.txt):

- `-B 1`: print one line *before* match's line
- `-A 2`: print two line *after* match's line

### Output

```text
    user1:
        password = *
        lastupdate = 1205877833
        flags =
--
    user2:
        password = *
        lastupdate = 1205877833
        flags =
```

Comment: Shoot, this is actually an AIX "shadow" file so it will not always be the same number of lines ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression in Perl like this:

```
perl -00 -ne '$p = "*"; print if /password\s*=\s*\Q$p\E/' file
```

The `-n` switch loops through the file one record at a time. The `-0` switch specifies the input record separator. `-00` is a special case, know as "paragraph mode". In this mode, each record is a paragraph of text, terminated by one or more empty lines. This works for your file, as there is an empty line between each user entry.

Set the variable `$p` to whatever the password is that you want to match. If the record contains the line "password = `$p`" (with any number of spaces in between) then the section will be printed.

Depending on your needs, you may want to make the regular expression a little more strict (this will match things like "password = *anything" but this one works for the sample you have provided.

Output:

```
    user1:
        password = *
        lastupdate = 1205877833
        flags = 

    user2:
        password = *
        lastupdate = 1205877833
        flags =
```

Comment: Can you elaborate about the `paragraph mode`?

Comment: @Edouard I've added some more explanation to my answer.